# How to generate HTML from Emacs Lisp documentation?

Tags: html, emacs, documentation

Emacs calls itself self-documenting. This means that you can use Emacs to read the documentation that is encoded in the Emacs-Lisp files.

Is there an easy way to export this documentation to HTML, so that the documentation can be placed on a website? I know that the FSF publishes the documentation at http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/emacs.html but not all of the Emacs modules are listed there.

**Update:** I'm interested in the documentation in the elisp files, not in texinfo files. I also want the documentation for the functions and for the "major mode". In the Emacs documentation viewer, this is all nicely hyperlinked and it would be great if that were preserved in HTML.

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Htmlize

Comment: See http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/10/17/Generate-emacs-lisp-documentation/. There is some code there that will make an org buffer of emacs lisp documentation that can be converted to html or pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the documentation is "encoded in Emacs-Lisp files". They're stored as texinfo documents that can be exported to HTML (which is I think how the GNU documentation site is generated). [texi2html](http://www.nongnu.org/texi2html/) can convert texinfo files into HTML.

The docstrings for the functions are stored in the elisp files directly. If you want those, you'll have to iterate through the list of functions, get the docstring and create an HTML file. I think it should be doable in a few lines of elisp.

Xah Lee comments [here](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/modernization_html_vs_info.html) on how they should be using HTML anyway.

Comment: It would be great if you can help getting to those few lines of elisp.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer may be to simply use/extend existing Lisp automatic documentation generators. Here are a few links that might get you there:

- [Albert](http://albert.sourceforge.net/)
- [atdoc](http://www.lichteblau.com/atdoc/doc/)
- [CLiki page on documentation tools](http://www.cliki.net/Documentation%20Tool)

Comment: None of these are for elisp are they?

Comment: Nope, they're for Common Lisp. That's what I mean by "use/extend"; one option is to take a more "main stream" CL autodoc tool and hack it to parse elisp correctly. Probably less effort than starting from scratch.

Comment: Any tool that supports search by name?